# Snakemake - How to produce multiple outputs from single input, multiple times with different seeds?

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to create a snakemake rule that produces 3 output files for each given seed. I currently have the following:

```
SIM_OUTPUT = ["summary", "tripinfo", "vehroute"]
SEEDS = [1,2]
single_seed = 1
rule sumo_sim_1:
    input:
        config = "two-hours-ad-hoc.sumo.cfg"
    output:
        expand("xml/{file}.{seed}.xml", seed = single_seed, file=SIM_OUTPUT)
    shell:
        " sumo -c {input.config} --seed {single_seed}" 
        "--summary-output {output[0]} "
        "--tripinfo-output {output[1]} " 
        "--vehroute-output {output[2]} "
```

The above code works for a single seed, but I cant get/think of a way to work for multiple seeds.

Comment: Do you *need* to specify the SIM_OUTPUT part through `expand`? With three files you could easily name and specify them individually in the output section (`summary_output = "xml/summary.{seed}.xml"` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your rule to make use of your seed wildcard like so

```
rule sumo_sim_1:
    output:
        "xml/summary.{seed}.xml",
        "xml/tripinfo.{seed}.xml",
        "xml/vehroute.{seed}.xml",
    shell:
        " sumo -c {input.config} --seed {wildcards.seed} "
        "--summary-output {output[0]} "
        "--tripinfo-output {output[1]} " 
        "--vehroute-output {output[2]} "
```

And then your downstream rule(s) can just specify the seed necessary for their input, like so:

```
rule all:
    input:
        ["xml/summary.1.xml", "xml/summary.2.xml", "xml/tripinfo.1.xml", "xml/tripinfo.2.xml", "xml/vehroute.1.xml", "xml/vehroute.2.xml"]
```